# Узнать сколько перемотано в блоке от низа

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно узнать сколько пикселей перемотано в div блоке считая от его низа. Если прокрутка промотана до самого конца, должно выдавать 0.

Пытаюсь поиграть с этими параметрами, но выдаёт не то:

```
var block = document.getElementById("mydiv");
alert (block.scrollTop + ' ' + block.scrollHeight);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var block = document.getElementById("mydiv");
if (block.scrollHeight - block.scrollTop === block.clientHeight) {
alert('Низ');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно посчитать вот так: **block.scrollHeight - block.scrollTop - block.offsetHeight**

```js
var block = document.getElementById("mydiv");
function calc() {
alert (block.scrollHeight - block.scrollTop - block.offsetHeight   + ' ' + block.scrollHeight);
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
 background: red;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.inner {
height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
<div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="calc()">calc</button>
```